# Data Labels in stack bar chart using geom_col()

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am quite new to R and I am trying to do a simple stacked bar chart.

This is my dataset:

```
game_systems <- tibble(system = rep(c("Playstation",
                                  "Nintendo",
                                  "XBox",
                                  "NeoGeo"), 4),
                   year = c(rep(2017, 4),
                            rep(2018, 4),
                            rep(2019, 4),
                            rep(2020, 4)),
                   price = c(rep(500, 4),
                             450, 550, 250, 1000,
                             400, 600, 125, 2000,
                             350, 650, 62.5, 4000))
```

Here is the code for the plot:

```
game_systems %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x = system, y = price, fill = year)) + 
 geom_col(position = "fill")
```

This produces the following:

[image]

Now I would like to add the % labels in the plot as data labels. I can't seem to find a way of doing this automatically other than manually having to create the % values myself and putting it in the "label" section of geom_text()

Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be done without calculating percentages manually, but it only takes a couple of extra lines of code. You can group the data by system, calculate the percent with the mutate() function, and then feed that data into ggplot():

```
game_systems %>% 
  group_by(system) %>% 
  mutate(percent = round(price/sum(price), 2)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = system, y = price, fill = year)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = percent),
              position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), 
              color = "white")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think @Jacob Rothschild's suggestion is more straightforward, but adding this in case you do want to do the calculation inside ggplot. `..y..` is a special variable produced when ggplot runs to give you access to the current y value being plotted in its context. So `..y../sum(..y..)` is equivalent to calculating `price/sum(price)` upstream of ggplot2. Then `position_fill(vjust = 0.5)` applies the same y "fill" that you have in `geom_col`, but with the added parameter that you want the labels to be halfway up each bar.

```
game_systems %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = system, y = price, fill = year)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..y../sum(..y..))), 
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For each bar, I'm trying to have a relative percentages (the sum of each column should be 100%). For easyness of interpretation, I changed the `x` and `fill` parameters. The code is:

```
game_systems %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = year, y = price, fill = system)) + 
   geom_col(position = "fill") +
   geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..y../sum(..y..))), 
        position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))
```

but actually the percentage are referred to the total of data. How is the code for the relative percentage. I tried different solutions, with wrong results (wrong percentages).

[image]

**Solution**

Firstly ggplot return an error:

The dot-dot notation (`..y..`) was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
ℹ Please use `after_stat(y)` instead.
So the code need a small adjustment, but I found a solution for my question without changing the original dataset. The idea behind is to work directly on percentage with the intermediate step of creating the total for each year.

```
game_systems %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(tot.year=sum(price),
         perc.year=round(100*price/tot.year,1)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = perc.year, fill = system)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(perc.year,"%")), 
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent)+
  ylab("Sells")
```

[image]